# understanding of separable space

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces

I would like to understand correctly what does mean separable space, from Wikipedia I am reading that.

In mathematics a topological space is called separable if it contains a countable, dense subset; that is, there exists a sequence $\{ x_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$  of elements of the space such that every nonempty open subset of the space contains at least one element of the sequence.

Also related to Hilbert space:

A Hilbert space is separable if and only if it has a countable orthonormal basis, it follows that any separable, infinite-dimensional Hilbert space is isometric to $ℓ^2.$

Can we apply  last  condition for all space? I mean space is separable if it contains finite  orthonormal basis? because this is much simple definition then previous, even I don't know exact definition of dense subset, that why   if it is possible to use orthonormal basis related to separable space? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, no: we can't since for "orthonormal basis" we need to have a vector space, which isn't available in the general case of topological spaces...

Comment: thanks for reply,so what would be simplest explanation of separable space?

Comment: @datodatuashvili: That's a good question.

Comment: thanks  @  Mhenni Benghorbal for reply

Comment: @datodatuashvili: You are welcome.

Comment: I think the simplest explanation is the one you already gave in your question, @datodatuashvili .

Comment: related to Hilbert transform or  to topology?ok last  question what does open subset means?

Comment: In addition to DonAntonio's comment, "orthonormal" doesn't even make sense in most vector spaces. You need to have an inner product structure - not even all normed spaces have an inner product.

Comment: please someone post as an answer

Comment: Can you explain more what the question is? The definition you gave is good... 

Maybe think about what separable means for the open sets.

Comment: we can translate this question like this separable space because it contains  word space,can be explained by vector spaces and  their basis?